# Returning false in GTM as custom Javascript when I know its true

Tags: javascript, boolean, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to create a javascript function in Google Tag Manager that will allow me to reduce the amount of triggers I need to create.

I want the tag to only fire if it is one of the videos in the var urlsToTest, but it returns false everytime. I have tested the individual URLs as conditions and they seem to work, but not in this function.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function() {
  var urlsToTest = [
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx',
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx',
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx',
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx',
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx-lv8'
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < urlsToTest.length; i += 1) {  
    if (google_tag_manager['GTM-xxxxxx'].dataLayer.get('gtm.videoUrl') > -1) {
      return true;
    }
  };

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Your loop does not involve values from the `urlsToTest` list.

Comment: You are not clear with problem, and purpose, and what do you need, and as @Pointy said you didn't use your `urlsToTest`. please try to explain problem and purpose, maybe some other solutions available for this problem

Comment: Pointy, I am still learning javascript. I found this code that was being used for checking page URL's then modified it for checking an element in GTM. So what/where would I need to add the `urlsToTest` in order for it to work?

Comment: Dupinder - I have 5 videos on 5 pages of a website. Instead of creating individual triggers for each of them I want to have 1 trigger that fires when these 5 specific videos are played.

Comment: I don't think you can do a datalayer.get in a variable (the point of datalayer.get is that you do not need a variable), and in any case it would be easier to use a lookup table that returns false as default and true for each of your video urls.  Then you can use that in a trigger.

Comment: @EikePierstorff that solved my issue. Thank you so much